# upload files with a dynamic path with django-ajax-uploader

Tags: ajax, django, file-upload

I am using this tool to upload files with ajax:
https://github.com/skoczen/django-ajax-uploader

It works well but I can't set the path of the file with dynamic parameters (static path works well).
Here is the relevant part of the code:

urls.py:

```
url(r'ajax-upload$', views.import_uploader, name="my_ajax_upload")
```

views.py:

```
import_uploader = AjaxFileUploader(UPLOAD_DIR='campaigns')
```

js:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader(
                {
                    action: "{% url 'campaigns:my_ajax_upload' %}",
                    element: input_element[0],
                    multiple: true,
                    onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) 
                    {
                    },
                    onAllComplete: function(uploads) 
                    {

                    },
                    params: 
                    {
                        'csrf_token': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                        'csrf_name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken',
                        'csrf_xname': 'X-CSRFToken',
                    },
                });
```

My path looks like this:

```
path='campaigns/campaign_{}/participation/participant_{}/question_{}/'.format(self.campaign.id, self.participant.id, self.answers.question.id)
```

How can I pass the dynamic parameters of the path to the AjaxFileUploader object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rename file with django-ajax-uploader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350508/rename-file-with-django-ajax-uploader)

Comment: Not exactly: this post deals with the PATH of the file while my other post deals with the NAME of the file. They both can be solved within one same view though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up using [jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).
See my post here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35860608/1875861

Comment: do you know how to implement dynamic input field with ajax please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69635523/upload-multiple-images-with-django-formset-and-ajax-request