# rename file with django-ajax-uploader

Tags: ajax, django, file, upload

I am using https://github.com/skoczen/django-ajax-uploader to upload a file in django. It works but I would like to rename the uploaded file during the process. I want to add a timestamp so I am sure it has a unique name.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up using [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). It allows to define the path of the file inside the view.Example:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^upload_question_photo/$', UploadQuestionPhoto.as_view(), name="upload_question_photo"),
```

**index.html**

```
var input=$(this).find("input");
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('photo', input[0].files[0]);
formData.append('question', input.attr("name"));
formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
input.fileupload(
{
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "{% url 'campaigns:upload_question_photo' %}",
    formData: formData,

    //the file has been successfully uploaded
    done: function (e, data) 
    {
        response=data.result;
        window.console&&console.log("Successfully uploaded!");
        window.console&&console.log(response.path);
    }.bind(this),

    processfail: function (e, data) 
    {
        window.console&&console.log('Upload has failed');
    }.bind(this)
});
```

**views.py**

```
class UploadQuestionPhoto(View):
    u"""Uploads photos with ajax 
    Based on the code  #https://github.com/miki725/Django-jQuery-File-Uploader-Integration-demo/blob/master/upload/views.py
    """

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print "UploadQuestionPhoto post"
        response={}

        question=str(request.POST["question"])       
        #path where the file is going to be stored
        path="/question/" + question + "/"
        photo_path=settings.MEDIA_ROOT + path

        # if 'f' query parameter is not specified -> file is being uploaded
        if not ("f" in request.GET.keys()):
            print "file upload"
            # make sure some files have been uploaded
            if request.FILES:
                # get the uploaded file
                photo_file = request.FILES["question_field_" + question]
                name_with_timestamp=str(time.time()) + "_" + photo_file.name

                # create directory if not exists already
                if not os.path.exists(photo_path):
                    os.makedirs(photo_path)

                # add timestamp to the file name to avoid conflicts of files with the same name
                filename = os.path.join(photo_path, name_with_timestamp)
                # open the file handler with write binary mode
                destination = open(filename, "wb+")
                # save file data with the chunk method in case the file is too big (save memory)
                for chunk in photo_file.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
                destination.close()

                #response sent back to ajax once the file has been successfuly uploaded
                response['status']='success'
                response["path"]=photo_path+name_with_timestamp


        # file has to be deleted (TODO: NOT TESTED)
        else: 
            # get the file path by getting it from the query (e.g. '?f=filename.here')
            filepath = os.path.join(photo_path, request.GET["f"])
            os.remove(filepath)
            # generate true json result (if true is not returned, the file will not be removed from the upload queue)
            response = True

        # return the result data (json)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")
```

Voilà ! Hope it helps.